# In a loop that results in several arrays, how to return an array with the sum of all of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, push

I have an array of strings that, after a lot of effort, I have managed to turn into several arrays with a loop. So right now, the loop is giving me something like:

```
[4,5,6,7,8]
[4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5]
[4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5],[22,33,44,55,66]
```

If I place the return lower in the code, I get:
`[[4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5],[22,33,44,55,66]]`

What I need is the vertical sum of these arrays, so in this case it'd be:
`[27,40,53,66,80]`

So far, I'm usign '.push'. Also, console.log gives me this answer but return results in 'undefined'. Any help with these two things would be welcome!

----UPDATE----

As someone here suggested, I tried this but it doesn't work entirely:

````
array=[ [ 1, 2, 4 ], [ 4, 1, 5 ], [ 0, 5, 2 ] ];
let adding=0
const result=[]
for (let i = 0; i < array[0].length; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
            adding += array[j][i];
            }
            result.push(adding);}
console.log(result)
    ```

The ouput is: [ 5, 13, 24 ] instead of [5,8,11]
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [22, 33, 44, 55, 66],
];

const result = arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr[i], 0));
console.log(result)
```

**2)** Using simple for loops

```js
const arr = [
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [22, 33, 44, 55, 66],
];

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; ++i) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; ++j) {
    sum += arr[j][i];
  }
  result.push(sum);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, although I am a beginner and don't understand any of this code, so if there's a simpler solution, I'd be very grateful

Comment: @beginner12345 Added another solution have a look

Comment: Thank you! I tried replicating it but it didn't work, any idea of what might be wrong?
```
array=[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 1, 3 ], [ 0, 5, 0 ] ];
let adding=0
const result=[]
for (let i = 0; i < array[0].length; ++i) {
    let sum=0;
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
            adding += array[j][i];
            }
            result.push(adding);}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: why are you creating `adding` variable, `sum` is already available and reset to `0` on each run [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/oNGYjEy?editors=0011)

Comment: I just changed the name because I have to use certain names for the exercise, but if you take a look, I'm not using sum, I just forgot to delete it

Comment: That's what causing a problem. You can't make it global and use it to add them...

Comment: If you want, you can name whatever you'd like to name the `sum`